# Given two lines, each defined using Hesse normal form find the intersection point.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

A line can be defined by two numbers : distance of line to origin and the angle from the origin to closest point on the line. Is there a formula to find the coordinates of intersection of two lines given this representation?

I can go to `y=a*x+b` representation for each line and calculate intersection point using basic algebra. However, vertical lines behave poorly. I can do a `if (angle == 0 or angle == pi){..` check, but checking if two `double`s are equal is pointless.

Comment: lol, you have asked this question several times and people answer the obvious way, kinda weird you accepted the answer in your last question, the answer below is basically the same.

Comment: @Anonymous You are not correct. The answer is different. It turns out I can use the a*x+b*y=1 form to define any line without the "if line is vertical - deal with a special case". This solves a lot of my design problems. I am glad that you follow my progress, anonymous.

Comment: yes but initally you were giving an angle as a parameter, If you try to transform it to ax+by=1, a or b will be a function of this angle and you will end up basically in the same scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the lines as $ax+by=c$ and $dx+ey=f.$ (This includes vertical lines.) Now, to find the intersection point you solve de system

$$\begin{cases}ax+by&=c\\ dx+ey&=f\end{cases}$$ to get

$$x=\dfrac{ce-bf}{ae-bd},\quad y=\dfrac{af-cd}{ae-bd}.$$ (Of course, this only works if the lines are not parallel.)

Comment: That was concise and right to the point. So, Can I define any line as ax+by=1? That would be so convenient.

Comment: No, take the non-vertical line given by $y=0$ for example.

Comment: It seems like you have reciprocals of x and y and correct formulas are:         
x =(c*e-f*b)/(a*e-d*b);
y =(c*d-a*f)/(b*d-a*e);

Comment: @Stepan You're right. Problem fixed. Thank you.